# URLs for items on a MVC site: use item id, item title, or both?

Tags: url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am developing a web site using ASP.NET MVC. The site will be similar to StackOverflow in that there will be user submitted items that will have a numeric id and a textual title.

Now I am thinking how to design the URL routing system for the "item details" pages. I had thought of using the id alone (as in `http://www.mysite.com/items/1234`) or the title alone (as in `http://www.mysite.com/items/how-to-foobarize-a-fizzbuzz`). I see however that StackOverflow uses instead both of them (as in `http://www.mysite.com/items/1234/how-to-foobarize-a-fizzbuzz`).

So which one is the best approach? And what is the point of using both the id and the title in the URL? Isn't this redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of using the title in that form (usually referred to as a "slug") is basically just that of URL readability. However, if you are not enforcing a uniqueness constraint on your titles then this will not necessarily be adequate to identify a record. Therefore, when both are used, the ID can be there for the server to actually to do the lookup and the slug is there for humans to read.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, having both ID and title (which is most often called [slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28web_publishing%29)) is redundant, but it's cool both from SEO and UX standpoints.

There's one personal dislike about how it's done here on SO, though. I can't seem to understand why an ID is separated from a slug with a forward slash (`/7754456/urls-for-item...`). To me, each segment implies some sort of hierarchy, so dash will be more appropriate `/7754456-urls-for-item...`). But that's just me.